# Merge 2 files separated with space

Tags: text-processing

I have two text files. The first "file1.txt" has content:

```
Apple
Orange
Banana
```

while the second file "file2.txt" has content:

```
monday
tuesday
wednesday
```

I want to combine them into one file and its output is:

```
Apple monday
Orange tuesday
Banana wednesday
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply with `paste` command:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt
```

---

To set a single space as a delimiter - add `-d' '` option: `paste -d' ' file1.txt file2.txt`